# How to reconstruct a categorical variable with multiple choices

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I've the following problem. I'm analyzing data from a questionnaire, where respondents were presented 7 possible answers and had to select 3 of them.
So what I have is a set of 7 dummy-variables, coded as 1 if the respondent selected the answer, and 0 otherwise.

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7
0  0  1  1  0  1  0
1  1  1  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  1  0  1
```

I would like to transform these dummies back to three variables, each including the answer given. That is something like:

```
choice1 choice2 choice3
 a3       a4      a6
 a1       a2      a3
 a2       a5      a6
```

I tried using tidyverse "gather", on the whole set of "a" variables

```
int <- old_df %>%  mutate_at(vars(a1:a7), ~ ifelse(. == 0, NA, .))
new <- int %>% gather("choice1", "present", a1:a7, na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, I don't get what I want, as I've just 1 variable, with all the possible "a" answers.

I also tried using "gather" with every single "a" variable, but again I don't get what I want, as I end up replicating the original dataset (with string variables rather than 1 and 0).

Any idea, how can I get the kind of data I would like to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_old <- read.table(text = "a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7
0  0  1  1  0  1  0
1  1  1  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  1  0  1", header = T)

df_old %>% mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(!rowid) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  mutate(choice = paste0('choice', seq_len(max(rowSums(df_old))))) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rowid, names_from = choice, values_from = name) %>%
  select(-rowid)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   rowid [3]
  rowid choice1 choice2 choice3
  <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1     1 a3      a4      a6     
2     2 a1      a2      a3     
3     3 a2      a5      a7
```

Comment: Thank you! That almost works. however I get an error message when using mutate and paste. the message is as follows:  " Problem with `mutate()` input `choice`.
x Input `choice` can't be recycled to size 3. The error occurred in group 1: rowid = 1."  If I set manually the number of repetitions (rather than using "max(RowSums())", I get the same error for a different "rowid".  Any idea why?

Comment: As follow up: I think I know the problem: some repsondents have selected only 2 and not 3 options, so some "rowid" groups cannot "fit in" the newly created varialbe "choice" with the pre-set number of repetitions

Comment: Solved! df_old %>% mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(!rowid) %>%
  filter(value != 0)%>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  mutate(choice = row_number())%>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rowid, names_from = choice, values_from = name) %>%
  select(-rowid)

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier in `base R`

```
out <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) names(x)[x == 1])))
names(out) <- paste0('choice', seq_along(out))
```

-output

```
out
#  choice1 choice2 choice3
#1      a3      a4      a6
#2      a1      a2      a3
#3      a2      a5      a7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), a2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), a3 = c(1L, 
1L, 0L), a4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L), a5 = c(0L, 0L, 1L), a6 = c(1L, 0L, 
0L), a7 = c(0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```